# Windows batch script point to proper path

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that I'm running from one folder, that is calling a .NET executable in another folder, and then passing in folder parameters to it that exist in another folder.  It looks like this:

```
SET start_dir=%cd%
cd..
cd apps
SET apps_dir=%cd%
SET my_dir=%apps_dir%\MY_DIR

cd C:\projects\ConsoleApplication1\src\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug

ConsoleApplication1.exe -i  -f %my_dir%

cd %start_dir%
```

Is this the proper way to pass in a directory to an application in a batch script?  My app doesn't seem to be able to find the directory and I didn't know if there was a way to troubleshoot these things in a script or if this is the proper way or not since it's the first time I've done a Windows batch script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be, but batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

This is important whenver there are spaces in file or directory names.

I'd suggest some minor changes:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal
SET "start_dir=%cd%"
cd ..
cd apps
SET "apps_dir=%cd%"
SET "my_dir=%apps_dir%\MY_DIR"

cd "C:\projects\ConsoleApplication1\src\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug"

ConsoleApplication1.exe -i  -f "%my_dir%"

cd "%start_dir%"
```

Noting

- @echo off turns off command-echoing for the duration of the batch
- setlocal ensures any environment changes made are backed-out when the batch ends so you don't get problems with stale data from changes made by prior runs
- cd "destinationdir" - the quotes are **not** usually required, even with "spaces in pathnames" but *may* be required for strange pathnames (like those containing `&`)
- "%my_dir%" as an argument for consoleapplication1 to ensure it's treated as a single token
- if `consoleapplication1.exe` is in a directory on the path, then there's no need to `cd` to that directory; the command `consoleapplication1 ....` will access it. Naturally, if the application is provided with an unqualified filename, then it will assume that the file is in the `current` directory, not the `executable`'s directory, so there may be a need to switch directories...
- if `consoleapplication1.exe` is in a directory which is not on the path, then `"C:\projects\ConsoleApplication1\src\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\consoleapplication1" ....` will access it. The quotes are harmless if included but required in the case of spaces in the full-executablename.
- `path` from the prompt will show the execution path; each directory separated by semicolons.
- it's possible to use

```dos
@echo off
setlocal
SET "start_dir=%cd%"
pushd ..\apps
SET "apps_dir=%cd%"
SET "my_dir=%apps_dir%\MY_DIR"
pushd "C:\projects\ConsoleApplication1\src\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug"

ConsoleApplication1.exe -i  -f "%my_dir%"
popd
popd
```

where `pushd` changes to the specified destination directory the current saved on a simple stack. `popd` pops the directories back from the stack.